# Getting a page.php error when I create a new page in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
        </div><!--END CONTAINER-->
        <?php 
            if (get_field('header_image')){
                $image = get_field('header_image');
                if (get_field('do_not_use_page_title')){
                    $title = get_field('alternate_page_title');
                }else {
                    $title = get_the_title();
                }
                if (get_field('subheading')) $subheading = get_field('subheading');
                ?>
                <div class="page-header" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image['url']?>);">
                    <?php echo "<h1>$title</h1>"; ?>
                    <?php if ($subheading) { echo "<h2>$subheading</h2>";} ?>
                </div>
                <?
            }
        ?>
        <div class="container">
        <div id="content" class="clearfix row">

            <div id="main" class="col-sm-8 clearfix" role="main">

                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('clearfix'); ?> role="article" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

                    <?php if (!(get_field('header_image'))) { ?>
                    <header>

                        <div class="page-header"><h1 class="page-title" itemprop="headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></div>

                    </header> <!-- end article header -->
                    <?php } ?>

                    <section class="post_content clearfix" itemprop="articleBody">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>

                    </section> <!-- end article section -->



                </article> <!-- end article -->


                <?php endwhile; ?>      

                <?php else : ?>

                <article id="post-not-found">
                    <header>
                        <h1><?php _e("Not Found", "wpbootstrap"); ?></h1>
                    </header>
                    <section class="post_content">
                        <p><?php _e("Sorry, but the requested resource was not found on this site.", "wpbootstrap"); ?></p>
                    </section>
                    <footer>
                    </footer>
                </article>

                <?php endif; ?>

            </div> <!-- end #main -->


        </div> <!-- end #content -->
```

When creating a new page in WP I get an error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/example.com/example/public_html/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/page.php on line 69
```

I haven't been able to find any errors in the php that would trigger this parse error. Other pages that were already present on the website work fine, but making new pages and then viewing/previewing them brings an empty page with the above error. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: line 17 your opening tag suddenly changes to:  <?, where you use <?php in the rest of your code. The short tags starts with "<?" and ends with "?>". Short style tags are only available when they are enabled in php.ini configuration file.

Comment: Your solution worked! Thank you for your expertise.

Comment: FYI PSR-1 states: PHP code MUST use the long <?php ?> tags or the short-echo <?= ?> tags; it MUST NOT use the other tag variations.